# recursive function to return a list of all connected nodes, given a certain node from network graph using python

Tags: python, recursion, networkx

I'm trying to write a function that will return a list of all the connected nodes in a sub-network, given a starting node from subgraph:

for example the following graph has two sub-networks, one red and one green, as shown in the following image:

[image]

using python's package called networkx, I've ran the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

G=nx.Graph()

G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_node(3)
G.add_node(4)
G.add_node(5)
G.add_node(6)

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(1,5)
G.add_edge(4,6)

def recurse(G, z , node):
    z.append(node)
    n = list(set(G.neighbors(node)) - set(z)) 
    if len(n) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        for i in n:
            if i not in z:
                z.extend(recurse(G, z, i))
                return z

z = []
f = recurse(G,z,1)
print(f)
```

The function is supposed to return the sub-group -> [1,2,3,5] when given (1) as starting node but it returns [1,2,3,1,2,3]

Any ideas how I can perform this task by tweaking the code or maybe using another method?

Thanks!

Comment: You should also be aware that there is already a built-in method in networkx for this.  `nx.node_connected_component(G, node)` returns all nodes in the connected component of `G` which contains `node`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you're not interested about the order the nodes are visited you could just do DFS and collect visited nodes to `set`:

```
def recurse(G, z, node):
    z.add(node)
    for i in G.neighbors(node):
        if i not in z:
            recurse(G, z, i)

z = set()
recurse(G,z,1)
print(z) # {1, 2, 3, 5}
```